# calling function from index.html and the function loops indefintely

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm trying to make a function that only shows a certain part of the html to users that have the right role. These are my functions:

nodejs/server.js

```
app.get('/api/isadmin', ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
  User.findById(req.user, function (err, user) {

    res.send(user);
  });
});
```

This is where the problem occurs, it will run indefintely:

```
<ul ng-if="isAdmin()">
   <li>
       <a ui-sref="admin">Admin</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Why is this happening? I've looked at Satellizer's isAuthenticated function and basically done the same thing.

EDIT:
Updated code:

adminservice.js

```
angular.module('App')
 .factory('AdminService', function ($q, $http, toastr) {

  return {
      getAdmin: function () {
          var httpget = $http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/isadmin');

          httpget.then(function (response) {
                var res = response.data.role;
                if (res == 'admin') {
                    console.log('true');
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    console.log('false');
                    return false;
                }
            }, function (result) {
                return $q.reject(result);
            });

          return httpget;

      }
  };
});
```

navbar.js

```
angular.module('App')
 .controller('NavbarCtrl', function($q, $scope, $auth, AdminService) {

  $scope.isAuthenticated = function() {
     return $auth.isAuthenticated();
  };

  AdminService.getAdmin().then(
    function (result) {
        $scope.isAdmin = result;
    });
});
```

both responses, true or false, can still see the Admin list element.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: `adminService.getAdmin()` doesn't return anything. Also a terrible approach to place a function in the view that will constantly make `$http` requests. Need to understand how digest cycles work and see how many times that gets called ... it;s far more than you think. Set a scope variable inside promise callback instead

Comment: @charlietfl I do see that my current approach is not good, but I've struggled to get it working all-together. What do you mean by setting a scope variable inside a promise check?

Comment: return `$http` from `adminService.getAdmin()` and in controller do something like `AdminService.getAdmin().then(function(result){ $scope.isAdmin = result; })`. then use that variable (not function) in `ng-if`

Comment: @charlietfl by 'use that variable' you mean the $scope.isAdmin? just by doing ng-if="isAdmin" ?

Comment: yes ... always use asynchronous calls to assign  scope property variables

Comment: @charlietfl Could you check my updated code? I think I did what you suggested, but even if it responds true or false, they can still see the button Admin.

Comment: so use dev tools console to see what `response.data.role` is and what is returned to controller. Also should probably change `return $q.reject(result);` to `return false` and also update html to `ng-if="isAdmin"`

Comment: You aren't using the deferred correctly. You should be returning the `deferred.promise` and then in your callbacks used use `.resolve(response)`. Check out the examples [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: @Clint that is an anti pattern when `$http` itself already returns a promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was about to write a lot of things. Since you figured out and updated your code, let me fix the existing problems. You need to `return` the promise instance from `getAdmin` function, not `httpget`.

```
angular.module('App')
 .factory('AdminService', function ($q, $http, toastr) {

  return {
      getAdmin: function () {
          var httpget = $http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/isadmin');

          return httpget.then(function (response) {
                var res = response.data.role;
                if (res == 'admin') {
                    console.log('true');
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    console.log('false');
                    return false;
                }
            }, function (result) {
                // just return false
                return false;
            });
      }
  };
});
```

Your controller looks fine. In the html part, tie ng-if with `isAdmin` property.

```
<ul ng-if="isAdmin">
   <li>
       <a ui-sref="admin">Admin</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Hope, this helps.

**Update**

Only returning `httpget` will return promise instance, but you will get the actual response in the resolve function. The response that you get calling `http://localhost:3000/api/isadmin`. See this plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/9UtYJlm9BalTi8HHTrV2?p=preview

Comment: I edited my promise in the adminservice with your method, and it seems to work, only one problem. it checks it once, and only once. So if you arent logged in, it wont check again even if you log in and are admin. But if I log in, open a new browser window the button will be there.

Comment: @KTown Why you want to check `isAdmin` again and again? Your controller loads when you go to that route/state or where you defined ng-controller. If you open another browser window and go to that route/state, the controller will load again and check `isAdmin`.

Comment: I figured that out yea. The reason is that I want the navbar to update if the user is admin or not, and then add the button or not based on that information. Satellizer's isAuthenticated() works that way, and I'm hiding and showing <ul>'s based on if its true or not, which is basically what I'm looking to do with this.

Comment: So, you are basically trying to create a method like `isAuthenticated`?

Comment: basically yea, but to check if the person is admin or not.

Comment: Glad to hear that! But unfortunately, Satellizer's auth implemention is out of this post's context. I just saw Satellizer's code. They used localStorage. When a user logs in, he calls server side and then stores auth token information in client side localStorage. The `isAuthenticated` function checks if the token is there in localStorage and whether it expired or not. That't it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111952/discussion-between-k-town-and-saad).